# How can i handle ‘Exit status 1’ during react server start

Tags: create-react-app, npm-start

I am implementing react app.
My environment is in intranet with no internet access.
So, I set react project in outside environment with internet access.
After copying project to intranet environment, I executed npm install and start.
But a error has occurred during starting below.

```
PS D:\workspaces\my-app> npm start
> my-app@0.1.0 start D:\workspaces\my-app
> react-scripts start

i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://10.225.168.119/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from D:\workspaces\my-app\public
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /

Starting the development server...
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)

Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs: [ '/s', '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', '"http://localhost:3000/"' ]
}

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\KTDS\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-02T02_03_07_566Z-debug.log
```

This project is working fine in outside env.
Is the solution to this issue?

Comment: When you installed your npm dependencies here did you do that on the same system? npm has to compile dependencies sometimes and that means an install on one system may not run on another.

Comment: I made the project on windows7 in ourter site. But I executed it on windows10 in intranet env. Can this be an reason?

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I don't know what your system is on the current machine. The fundamental question here is: Are the operating systems different? Are the node versions different? npm version... etc. If so then it's most likely not compatible

Comment: ok. I will check it. Thank you.

Comment: I checked it. But there are same operation system, same node version, same npm version between internal env and outernal env. And I compared npm fund of each project. There is same version, too. What else can I check?

Comment: I resloved this issue. I added path(\windows\System32). Thank you.